# basic ruby script not working as expected

Tags: ruby, git, shell

I'm trying to write a simple ruby script to update my GIT working directories.  The script is producing errors and I cannot figure out why.  I have the following function ( I know that can be written more simply, but nothing i try seems to work)

```
def performCommandInDir(command, dir)
  old_dir = Dir.pwd
  Dir.chdir(dir)
  system(command)
  Dir.chdir(old_dir)
end
```

and I call it like so

```
performCommandInDir("git svn rebase", repo[:name])
```

When I run the script I see the following errors:

```
fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase cannot be used without a working tree.
rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

I have verified that repo[:name] is the correct path to my GIT repository.  I can manually paste its value into a shell and the git commands work fine.

What could be going on here?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not just use ruby-git? https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an exact answer to your question, but you can pass `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` to git commands to tell it where to operate, that might help you.

I'm assuming this isn't a bare git repository since your rebasing on it, so that means the git dir is in `.git`:

```
system("git --git-dir=#{repo[:name]}/.git --work-tree=#{repo[:name]} svn rebase")
```

Comment: This seemed to fix my problems.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a chdir option on the system command - you could just do:

```
def performCommandInDir(command, dir)
  system(command, :chdir => dir)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the actual directory, change it and switch it back by using Dir.chdir with a block:

```
Dir.chdir(dir) do
  # your actions
end
# back in the original directory
```

Your error looks like a Git problem, not a Ruby problem. It seems you are in the wrong directory.

You may use `Dir.pwd` to check the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

My way to solve problem:

```
def performCommandInDir(command, dir)
    system("cd #{dir} && #{command}")
end
```

Comment: What's the point of using `Dir.chdir` if you're also going to do `cd #{dir}` in the `system` call?

Comment: I haven't any ideas to use this script, but @darren use some ugly ways to back in old path in 2 & 5 lines of his example. I think you're right and it is unnecessary.